# handling multiple images w/ various sizes JSON

Tags: ios, json

```
"pictures": {
      "sizes": [
        {
          "width": 100,
          "height": 75,
          "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/566955426_100x75.jpg?r=pad",
          "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F566955426_100x75.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
        },
        {
          "width": 200,
          "height": 150,
          "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/566955426_200x150.jpg?r=pad",
          "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F566955426_200x150.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
        },
        {
          "width": 295,
          "height": 166,
          "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/566955426_295x166.jpg?r=pad",
          "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F566955426_295x166.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
        },
        {
          "width": 640,
          "height": 360,
          "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/566955426_640x360.jpg?r=pad",
          "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F566955426_640x360.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
        },
        {
          "width": 960,
          "height": 540,
          "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/566955426_960x540.jpg?r=pad",
          "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F566955426_960x540.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
        },
        {
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 720,
          "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/566955426_1280x720.jpg?r=pad",
          "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F566955426_1280x720.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I am working on an ios app.
This is the JSON I am working with from the Vimeo API, and I want to know what is the proper way to handle these various images. I would like to grab the one with the height of 540, but in some cases the height might be 541, or something else. Also what if there is no image with a height of 540, should I grab the last image by default? What is the proper way to handle this? Should I just try and grab the second to last image (which is the one with height: 540 most of the time) and if there is only one image grab that one? From a production standpoint, how is this type of situation usually handled? Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is up to you. Iterate through the list of images and find the one that is exactly 540. If that doesn't exist, it is up to you what to use instead. You can use the one that is closest to 540 (either bigger or smaller as you see fit). Picking the next larger one is probably best. It's usually better to make a larger image a little smaller than trying to show a smaller image scaled larger.